# Excel bar chart widths displaying incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Using the following data to create a bar chart displays incorrect bar widths.

```
    Yes No
a   7   0
b   7   0
c   6   1
```

Shows

[image: Chart 1]

As you can see, the widths for c are incorrect. The 'No' column is showing as wider than the 'Yes' column despite the data being 6 and 1 respectively.

If I switch column order to show 'No' first and then 'Yes', the chart displays correctly.

[image: Chart 2]

Am I going mad or is this an obscure excel bug?

Other Info:
I'm running Office 365, Excel version 1808 (Build 10730.20102)

Comment: If you look at the axis, I'm sure you understand why, don't you. Change axis settings.

Comment: @WillCalderwood,, my suggestion is, instead of Stacked Bar better use  Clustered Bar Graph to get proper visualization of  data. Check my post I've reproduced the required graph. ☺

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks... that seems like an odd default! It only seems to do it with 6 and 1 or multiples of.

Comment: If the minimum in the data is >5/6 of the maximum, Excel decides you don't want your axis minimum to be zero. This was an arbitrary design decision made in the mid-90s, and it haunts us still.

Answer (score -2):

*For proper Data visualization use `Clustered Bar graph`.*

[image]

**N.B.** *I've used Office 2016 to reproduce the Graph.*

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, and should be a comment. Suggesting a completely different bar graph as *proper* is improper ;)

Comment: @TomBrunberg, OP has created Stacked Bar & I've use the Clustered Bar and exactly what I've  written in comments. OP was unable to find the Scale as per data for Bar on graph. The graph I've reproduced showing the proper scale for data i.e. for `YES 7,7 & 6` and for `NO is 0,0 & 1`.

Comment: OP wants to use stacked bar. OP did not know about the automatic scaling (in some circumstances). The correct answer would be to guide them to use the axis settings. Once again, suggesting another type of graph is not the answer!

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Stacked & Cluster both belongs to the same category since I found just change the Sub Category will help the OP to get rid form the issue, so that I've suggested. It's similar like replacing the Command to achieve the goal ☺